# Convergence radius of power series exam question

Tags: power-series

So I just did my analysis exam and I had this question where I needed to find the convergence radius for this power series. I did not really know what to do because of the $n!$ and the $(-1)^n.$ There must be a trick since it was part of a longer question.
Any ideas?
$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+1}\left(n-1\right)}{n!}\left(x-1\right)^n$$

Comment: Hint: the ratio test handles factorials well.

Comment: But doesn't the sequence need to not be $0$ for all $n$?

Comment: @MolecularPrime Why would it need to be always nonzero?

Comment: $\mathrm{\:and\:}\lim _{n\to \infty }|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$, how am I to divide by $a_n$ if it's $0$?

Comment: @MolecularPrime But that is a limit.  If $a_n$ is eventually nonzero, why would you need $a_n$ to be nonzero for all $n$?  You are looking at limiting behaviour, not what happens when $n$ is small.

Comment: I agree. I thought I could remove the terms that are $0$ but my stupid book said to only use that when $a_n$ is not $0$ for all $n$.

Comment: No coefficient is zero.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Except when $n=1$.  ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the ratio test - an AP calculus classic trick.

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right | &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{(-1)^{n+2} (n+1-1) (x-1)^{n+1} }{(n+1)!} \cdot \frac{ n!}{(-1)^{n+1} (n-1) (x-1)^{n} } \right| \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{(-1) (n) (x-1)}{(n+1)} \cdot \frac{1}{(n-1)} \right| \\
&= |x-1| \lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{n + 1} + \frac{1}{n-1} \right) \right|
\end{align*}

You can finish it here - or use Xander's answer (I was beat while writing this up).

Answer (score 1):

The radius of convergence of a power series
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n (x-x_0)^n $$
is given by
$$ \frac{1}{\limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{\left|a_n\right|}}. $$
This can be checking using the root test for series convergence.  But
$$ \limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{ \left| \frac{(-1)^{n+1} (n-1)}{n!} \right|}
= \limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac{n-1}{n!}}
= 0. $$
From this, it follows that the radius of convergence is $\infty$.  That is, the series converges absolutely for all $x$.